# fheider datatables init error

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, php-5.6

Morning to all. I'm trying to implement Datatables into my CakePHP 3 project and I'm having several problems.

When trying to `->init` datatable in a users list main view, I'm getting this error.

```
Class 'DataTables\Lib\CallbackFunction' not found in fheider/cakephp-datatables/src/View/Helper/DataTablesHelper.php
```

My PHP Version is 5.6.30 on cakePHP 3 and I'm using proper fheider datatable plugin for both versions.

Comment: Without giving more information (e.g. the code where you're calling this function), it's really hard for anyone to give useful help. One possible reason could be that you don't have your composer autoload file set up correctly, so that it is not finding the class. But there are many other possibilities.

Comment: Made title match the problem and added 1 code formatting to the body. Removed one tag as it should be used when asking about code branch specific issues according to its tag text.